# Where to find ICs in package sizes good for soldering?

Tags: integrated-circuit, soldering

I'd like to know the best places to find ICs that you can solder with. A lot of the package sizes I come across are way too small to solder by hand. I prefer through hole and sockets (like pdip), but ultimately anything with enough pin spacing will work.

In this particular instance, I'm looking for digpots. Although I can find some in pdip, they don't have the right specs: 256 positions, 5k supporting I2C (preferably quad channel, but I can work with single channel).

Comment: If the big 3 don't have something as mundane as that then you're not likely to find it.

Comment: The big three being who? I've been using mouser and allied.

Comment: Hsnd soldering leaded surface mount parts like soic, tqfp, etc is not hard - you just have to realize that it is flux and surface tension, rather than tip size or accuracy which gets the right connections made and the wrong ones not made.  As long as you only solder one corner pin before double checking alignment, more flux and fine gauge desolder braid will fix the occasional mistake or bridge.

Comment: Mouser, Digikey, Newark/Element14, probably.

Comment: Switch to a SPI interface?

Comment: I'll use the SPI interface as a last resort, as that buss's ability to address is limited.